# zend layout 26 times

Tags: zend-framework, optimization, layout

When i start working on new project, i find big issuse.
Main.phtml layout executed 26 times for every page.

```
<?= $this->doctype() ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
    <?
        $adapter = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
            'host'     => 'xxx',
            'username' => 'xxx',
            'password' => 'xxx',
            'dbname'   => 'xxx'
         ));
         $adapter->query('SET NAMES UTF8');

         $debug = $adapter->select()
                 ->from (array ('d'=>'debug'))
                 ->where ('id = ?',1)
                 ->query()
                ->fetchAll();
         $pageCount = $debug [0] ['page'];
         $pageCount +=1;
         $debug [0]['page'] = $pageCount;
         $adapter ->update('debug', $debug [0], $debug [0] ['id']);
?>
    <head>
        <?= $this->headMeta() ?>
        <?= $this->headTitle() ?>
        <?= $this->headScript() ?>
        <?= $this->headLink() ?>
        <?= $this->headStyle() ?>
```

I put count in head of that layout for check it value in database. 26 times for every page!
So i have questions about Zend.
1. How many times one layout for one page must be executed?
2. Where i can find part, who realy call that layout?

```
from
public/index.php. {main}:37
to
zend->view->_run:105
```

It all what i can find in callstack, it going 26 times on every page.

bootstrap

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends ExtZF_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $moduleAutoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath'  => realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..'),
        ));

        $moduleAutoloader->addResourceTypes(array(
            'core' => array(
                'namespace' => 'Core',
                'path'      => 'core'
            )
        ));
    }

    protected function _initConfig()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('frontController');

        $router     = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
        $request    = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();

        $router->route($request);

        $module = $request->getModuleName();

        $configPath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..') . '/configs/modules/' . $module . '.ini';

        $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(
            $configPath,
            APPLICATION_ENV
        );

        $this->setOptions($config->toArray());
    }

    protected function _initSettings()
    {
        $this->_bootstrap('db');

        $settingsGateway = new Model_SettingOption_Gateway();

        $settings = $settingsGateway->fetch()->toConfig();
        App::getConfig()->merge($settings);
    }

    protected function _initCache()
    {
        $this->_bootstrap('cachemanager');

        Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache(
                App::getCacheManager()->getCache('database'));

        Zend_Locale::setCache(
                App::getCacheManager()->getCache('default'));
    }

    public function _initRoutes()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('locale');

        $langRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            ':lang',
            array(
                'lang'       => '',
                'module'     => 'default',
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action'     => 'index'
            ),
            array(
                'lang' => "^(ru|en)$"
            )                
        );

        $defaultRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module(
            array(
                'module'     => 'default',
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action'     => 'index'
            )
        );
        $defaultRoute = $langRoute->chain($defaultRoute);

        $router = $this->getResource('FrontController')->getRouter();
        $router->addRoute('langRoute', $langRoute);
        $router->addRoute('defaultRoute', $defaultRoute);
    }

    protected function _initPlugins()
    {
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $frontController->registerPlugin(new Plugin_ContextAction())
                        ->registerPlugin(new Plugin_ErrorHandler())
                        ->registerPlugin(new Plugin_Ssl())
                        ->registerPlugin(new Plugin_View());
    }

    protected function _initViewHelpers()
    {
        ExtZF_Grid::setCellPartial('_partials/grid/cell.phtml');
        ExtZF_Grid::setRowPartial('_partials/grid/row.phtml');
        ExtZF_Grid::setHeaderPartial('_partials/grid/header.phtml');
        ExtZF_Grid::setTablePartial('_partials/grid/table.phtml');
        ExtZF_Grid::setHeaderSortPartial('_partials/grid/header-sort.phtml');
        ExtZF_Grid::setCheckBoxPartial('_partials/grid/check-box.phtml');
        ExtZF_Grid::setFormPartial('_partials/grid/form.phtml');
        ExtZF_Grid::setTextFilterPartial('_partials/grid/textFilter.phtml');
        ExtZF_Grid::setRangeFilterPartial('_partials/grid/rangeFilter.phtml');
        ExtZF_Grid::setSelectFilterPartial('_partials/grid/selectFilter.phtml');
        ExtZF_Grid::setFilterButtonsPartial('_partials/grid/filterButtons.phtml');
        ExtZF_Grid::setMassActionsPartial('_partials/grid/massActions.phtml');
    }

    protected function _initHelpers()
    {
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(
            'ExtZF/Controller/Action/Helper/', 'ExtZF_Controller_Action_Helper'
        );
    }
}
```

IndexController

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

set_include_path(
    implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
        realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'), 
        realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/ExtZF'),
        get_include_path()
    )
));                             

// Zend_Application
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
require_once 'Zend/Config/Ini.php';
require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/App.php';

// Set configuration
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini',
        APPLICATION_ENV, true);

App::setConfig($config);

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    $config
);

$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell where the error lies in that case, sounds like something wrong with the Action Stack maybe, it would be helpful to have a look at your application/Bootstrap.php and maybe the public/index.php as well as the application/default/controllers/IndexController.php

Comment: Looks like when i load every image, i execute layout again.

Comment: I think it could be the image loading - do you have images in your layout or content further down? Could it be that they don't load correctly? And if so, what happens when you put the URL to an image into your browser?
I suspect it could be that Zend Framework thinks the image paths are actually ZF-Routes that it can't resolve and therefore throws an error which loads the whole layout again in the background.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I found problem, problem was in htacces.
If we don't have image, we reload page again.
I don't have 26 of images, so i reload page 26 times.